# перестал работать сайт на Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, сервер

Здравствуйте у меня такой вопрос. Есть сайт который работал нормально он стоит на сервере компании. И он перестал работать ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ошибку обнаружить не могу даже при включении соответствующего кода в файле wp-config. В чем может заключаться проблема спросил у сис админа говорит что ip работает и ошибка в сайте. Также попробовал переименовать плагины но без результативно

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: WordPress тут ни при чем

Comment: тогда в чем заключается проблема

Comment: я попробовал запустить сайт на openserver и он работает

Comment: Гнать сисадина поганой метлой.